# How to squash a div vertically in center?

Tags: html, css, less, transform, css-transforms

I need to squash a div in vertically, using css3, the div need to have 100% width to fit in full window, but i don't know how. Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqUs8.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Updated, due to the request with an image behind the `<div>`)*

## A possible way if the background has only one color (white in this case)

```
div {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 40px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

div::before,
div::after {
    border-radius: 140px / 20px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;    
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

div::before {
    box-shadow: 0 50px 0 10px #FFFFFF inset;
    bottom: -80px;
}

div::after {
    box-shadow: 0 -50px 0 10px #FFFFFF inset;
    top: -80px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kmjLqrq2/

The css above uses two pseudoelements to make two ellipses above the `<div>`.

The problem now, if we have a `background-image` hiding behind the `<div>` is that our two ellipses will overlap our image.

## Enter [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient):

We can change our two pseudoelements now and give them an transparent ellipse as a `background-image` which will "fade" to black.

```
div::before,
div::after {
    background-size: 100% 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 25px;    
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

div::before {
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%, #000 76%);
    background-position: center bottom;
    top: -25px;
}

div::after {
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%, #000 76%);
    background-position: center top;
    bottom: -25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kmjLqrq2/1/

*(Note that the example above is only for Webkitbrowsers to keep it simple, please remember to use all vendor prefixes)*

Comment: Yes, but I have a picture behind the element, so, needs to be transparent

Comment: Updated my answer for the requirements.